# for loop not working in less css mixin

Tags: css, npm, gruntjs, less

I have noticed that a piece of Less I thought was working as expected is not actually generating all the styles I need - my for loop is not working.

The less in question is:

```
.for(@list, @code) {
    & {
        .loop(@i:1) when (@i =< length(@list)) {
            @value: extract(@list, @i);

            @code();

            .loop(@i + 1);
        }

        .loop();
    }
}

.role-variants(@variants, @props){
    .for(@variants, {
      .security_class_@{value} {
        @props();
      }
    });
}

@admin-roles: admin, admin_manager, admin_user, admin_manager_user;

html{
    body{
        &.admin{
            .role-variants(@admin-roles, {display: block;});
        }
    }
}
```

on http://less2css.org/ this compiles correctly, generating the classes I expect.

When I compile locally, I only get the following class:

```
html body.admin .security_class_admin {
    display: block
}
```

My for loop is not working locally, though it seems to be valid and working using the less compiler. Any ideas on how I can modify it to work locally, or perhaps I need to update my environment to a specific version, though it seems to be up to date.

Thanks again for your help.

Jamie

Comment: I see that people are looking but no suggestions are forthcoming - if there is any info missing or more detail I can add to help paint a better picture of the issue I am having please ask - I'll do my best to provide as much detail as possible. If you were in this situation, what would your process be for isolating the issue? Any steps or checks I might have missed? Thanks again ;)

Comment: Please edit your question and try to reduce your code to the point from which your error is easy to reproduce : [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks for the feedback Ivan, thanks Ali Torabi for being unhelpful and sarcastic.

I have updated the question with a whittled down extract of my app's code that I hope will simplify and clarify the issue I am having.

Comment: What are you using to compile? A code editor, grunt, gulp, cli... What version of less you have?

Comment: thanks blonfu - I'm using Grunt to compile - from my package.json:"grunt-contrib-less": "^1.3.0",

I thought it might have been a version issue, but with more digging and testing I found that my loop simply wasn't looping properly - with no way (that I know of) to set break points on the less file I could only see the malformed result, but all seems to be working as expected now - I can post my full code if you're interested in seeing the full class generation automation - it is pretty complex in the end.

Answer (score 0):

my loop was malformed - this loop now works as expected:

```
.for(@list, @code) {
    & {
        .loop(@i) when (@i > 0) {
            @value: extract(@list, @i);
            @code();
            .loop((@i - 1));
        }
        .loop(length(@list));
    }
}
```

Comment: with this code and with the other I get the same CSS but in reverse order: https://s32.postimg.org/e5kyuaq0l/lessfor.png